# NoSuchMethodException in cocos2d-android

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android

I am using cocos2d for android. The CCCallFunc is not working anywhere. It is always throwing NoSuchMethodException.

The CCCallFuncN

```
CCCallFuncN hideFunction = CCCallFuncN.action(this,
                    "hidesSprite");
```

My method

```
public void hidesSprite (CCNode sprite) {
        sprite.setVisible(false);
    }
```

This code is in public class PageLayer extends CCLayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the parameter type to Object:

```
    public void hidesSprite (Object sender) {

        Sprite sprite = (Sprite) sender;
        sprite.setVisible(false);
    }
```